# Function with eval won't make it through minification

Tags: javascript, eval, minify, google-closure-compiler

Here is my weird function that let my users create their own javascript code

```
function evalThisFunction(functionBody){        
     var func;
     eval("func = " + functionBody);
     return func;
}
```

But after minification with Closure Compiler (http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/), I get this result :

```
function a(b){eval("func = "+b);}
```

Do you see a way I can modify my weird function so it will still works after minification?

Comment: Then of course there's the obvious question - what are you trying to accomplish here with that function?

Comment: My user have access to a textarea where they can define a function, and then use it right away.

Comment: That actually sounds like a reasonable use case. Function constructor is the way to go then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, use the [Function constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function):

```
function evalThisFunction(functionBody){        
     return Function(functionBody);
}
```

Alternatively, you can swap out the above code entirely for `Function` , it seems to do what you want anyway. `eval` has scoping issues.

Comment: Notice however that if `"func = " + functionBody` was valid, then `functionBody` actually was a whole function expression.

Comment: @Bergi nice call. In that case, we'd have to use a `.indexOf` check and remove the surrounding `function(){` and `}`. Wonder why the parameter was named `functionBody` then :)

Comment: Like so: `"function(){ code code code; }".replace(/function\(\)\{(.*)\}/,"$1")` which returns `code code code;`.

Comment: Rather `var m = functionExpression.match(/function[^\(]*\(([^\)]*)\)\s*{([^\}]*)}/); return new Function(m[1], m[2]);` to get the arguments right

Comment: Using eval() is just bad practice. Using the Function contructor is the right way to do this.

Comment: Oops, make that `([^\}]*)` from my regex a `([^]*)` - braces should of course be allowed in the body.

Comment: Seems like neat solution! And you are right, "functionBody" wasn't named well (I'll fix that). I just saw that Function() can also take function's parameters, so everything seems good for my use case! Thank you!