# Error with eval while minification in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, eval, bundling-and-minification

I have an issue with eval() in javascript code. Can someone help me in fixing the issue. Below is my code for adding menu buttons by using a loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < organizedADMINMenuDetails.length; i++) {
            var menuItem = Ext.create('Ext.button.Button', {
                text: organizedADMINMenuDetails[i].menuName.toString().trim(),
                itemId: organizedADMINMenuDetails[i].menuuid.toString().trim(),
                iconCls: organizedADMINMenuDetails[i].iconcls.toString().trim(),
                plain: true,
                handler: function (self, e) {
                    hideNorthRegionMenuToolBars();
                    eval("fn_" + self.itemId + "();");
                }
            });
}

var fn_menuitem_Admin_Manager = function () {
        var url = "";
        tabDetails = {
            tabId: 'ManagerReports',
            title: 'Manager Reports',
            url: url
        }
        top.mmdApp.navigation.openTab(tabDetails);
    };

    var fn_menuitem_Admin_PracticeSetup = function () {
        var url = " ";
        tabDetails = {
            tabId: 'PracticeSetup',
            title: 'Practice Setup',
            url: url
        }
        top.mmdApp.navigation.openTab(tabDetails);
    };
```

While minification, MVC changes the javascript function name to some hi, si or pi and when I do an eval(button id), the function is not found and my application is throwing an error. How can I resolve this issue? Please help...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Function with eval won't make it through minification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22699745/function-with-eval-wont-make-it-through-minification)